# Microsoft IIS Error - Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: iis

I am running a third party application on Windows Server 2003 and IIS. Requests to specific pages (which process a lot of data) fails with this error:

> ```
> Error: 
> Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. 
> Number: 
> 0x8007000E
> ```

This is most likely an issue with the software itself and I already know it should be fixed at code level, but this is up to this third party.

What I am looking for is a way of alleviating this issue by configuring IIS properly (for example: increase buffer and memory allocated for applications). I can easily upgrade the server memory if required.

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890425
http://forums.iis.net/t/1053665.aspx

A few possibly helpful links from the above:

> - [Finding IIS Bottlenecks using Server Performance Advisor 2.0](http://www.iis.net/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=26&i=19)
>
>   [IIS 6.0 Service Pack 1 Tracing: Inside and Out](http://www.iis.net/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=26&i=20)
>
>   [Configuring IIS for Misbehaving Visual Basic Components](http://www.iis.net/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=26&i=21)
>
>   [Using IIS 6.0 Tracing to Effectively Diagnose Web Server Problems](http://www.iis.net/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=26&i=31)
>
>   [IIS Architecture Overview](http://www.iis.net/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=26&i=25)

Answer (score 0):

A Google search on the error message and 'iis' kicked this back: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-129327-p-1.html

For that guy, he found out from MS that IIS only supports 25 IP addresses (or fewer) on a server.

Does you server have more than 25?

Comment: No. 1 Single IP :(